# Heatmap colorbar issue using Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am plotting a heatmap using the array `T` which carries the same element. But the colorbar seems to show a range of values. How can I adjust it so that it shows only one value i.e. `0.01109`?

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T=np.array([[0.01109, 0.01109, 0.01109],
       [0.01109, 0.01109, 0.01109],
       [0.01109, 0.01109, 0.01109]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(T)

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
ax.set_title('\u03C3' ' ' "(N/m)")
```

[image]

Comment: You want there to be only a single tick? E.g., `cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)`
`cbar.set_ticks([0.01109])`?

Comment: what is the point of attaching a colorbar to an image where you know in advance that it has just one color?